# Unset rand() output from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to remove `$win` value from array and print all names except to winner. please check below code.

```
<html>
<p>
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$array=array();
array_push( $array,"preet");
array_push($array,"limbu");
array_push($array,"nik");
array_push($array,"rohit");
array_push($array,"ravi");
// Sort the list
sort($array);
echo"all guys are ".$f=join(", ",$array);
echo"<br>Lets see who is winner</br> ";
$len=count($array);
// Randomly select a winner!
$win=strtoupper( $array[rand(0,$len-1)]);


// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
echo "$win";

//print name of all except to winner.but given below code is not working
unset($win);
print"<br> sory ".join(",",$array);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I guess you must elaborate a little. Bear over with my sarcastic SO-fellows.

Comment: Voting for close as very unclear question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to unset the entry of the winner in your `$array`

```
<?php

// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$array = array();
array_push($array, "preet");
array_push($array, "limbu");
array_push($array, "nik");
array_push($array, "rohit");
array_push($array, "ravi");
// Sort the list
sort($array);
echo"all guys are " . $f = join(", ", $array);
echo"<br>Lets see who is winner</br> ";
$len = count($array);
// Randomly select a winner!
$random = rand(0, $len - 1);
$win = strtoupper($array[$random]);


// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
echo $win;

//print name of all except to winner.but given below code is not working
unset($array[$random]);
print"<br> sory " . join(",", $array);
```

Comment: Can you justify the -1 ?

Comment: hey man i am newbie in php. i learnt  somwhere that we need to  use  -1 to get value of last element of array. plz guide me if i am wrong . thanks

Comment: Why do you want to get the last element of an array ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to know the index of the value in the array to remove the item from the array.

You can do this using the [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function and then use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the value.

```
if(($key = array_search($win, $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$win]);
}
```